# Repeat acronym in conclusion

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

Can I use acronyms and abbreviations in the conclusion of a scientific paper or should I avoid them?

Even though the main idea of acronyms and abbreviations is to avoid repetition, my impression is that acronyms should be avoided as a conclusion should be somehow self explanatory.

Is there a consensus on something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **abstract** should be self-contained, so any abbreviations used therein should be explained at first occurence (if a term occurs only once, then there is no need to introduce an abbreviation), and **citations** should be given in its full form (i.e., [Name, Journal, Volume, Pages, Year]). Then starting from the **Introduction**, one introduces abbreviations at their first occurence ***again***, even if they were introduced already in the abstract.

And while I somewhat understand the desire to keep the **Conclusions** self-contained, too, at times when I wanted to do so either the reviewer or the language editor insisted that there should be only abbreviations once they are introduced. **Personally**, I don't like starting a sentence from an acronym, or a number, but the editors don't have such dillemas; so I usually just write so that there are none at the beginning of a sentence.

I once argued about it with the reviewer, but the language editor then again said to stick to abbreviations. I guess there are more chances to get it one's way in case of a very long paper (>50, or even >100 pages) for the sake of clarity.

Comment: So, basically you agree with me but the feedback you often get is that it's not acceptable :-) Well... who's right and who's wrong then?

Comment: @MedNait It's more a matter of writing style. I see your point, but don't agree 100% - I also appreciate the brevity that the editors seek.

Comment: After a second thought, using abbreviations in the conclusion section of a few-pages paper don't seem necessary. And as you hinted to, their use might be justified in case of a long paper/book.